# How do I collect from multiple iterator types?

Tags: rust

I am attempting to implement a new trait for a String that has a function that capitalizes the first letter of each String and un-capitalizes the rest. I am basing the function's interface on `to_uppercase()` and `to_lowercase()` in the Rust Standard Library.

```rust
use std::io;

trait ToCapitalized {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String;
}

impl ToCapitalized for String {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String {
        self.chars().enumerate().map(|(i, c)| {
            match i {
                0 => c.to_uppercase(),
                _ => c.to_lowercase(),
            }
        }).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).ok().expect("Unable to read from stdin.");

    println!("{}", buffer.to_capitalized());
}
```

This code is based on a suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544542/modifying-chars-in-a-string-by-index), but the code is outdated and causes multiple compilation errors. The only issue I am having with my implementation now is the following error:

```
src/main.rs:10:13: 13:14 error: match arms have incompatible types [E0308]
src/main.rs:10             match i {
                           ^
src/main.rs:10:13: 13:14 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:10:13: 13:14 note: expected type `std::char::ToUppercase`
src/main.rs:10:13: 13:14 note:    found type `std::char::ToLowercase`
src/main.rs:12:22: 12:38 note: match arm with an incompatible type
src/main.rs:12                 _ => c.to_lowercase(),
```

So in short, the return values of `fn to_uppercase(&self) -> ToUppercase` and `fn to_lowercase(&self) -> ToLowercase` can't be collected together because the map now has multiple return types.

I've attempted trying to cast them to another common Iterator type such as `Bytes` and `Chars`, but these iterator types can't be collected to form a String. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the implementation for `pub fn to_uppercase(&self) -> String` [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/str.rs), I devised a solution that is a bit of a hybrid between Dogbert and DK.'s solutions and the implementation given in the standard library. It even works with Unicode!

```
fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String {
    match self.len() {
        0 => String::new(),
        _ => {
            let mut s = String::with_capacity(self.len());
            s.extend(self.chars().next().unwrap().to_uppercase());
            s.extend(self.chars().skip(1).flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase()));
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Rust Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=118af6f3d0160a9458356e2a1e75fcbe&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Edit: For greater visibility, Shepmaster's simplified and optimized solution:

```
fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String {
    let mut s = String::with_capacity(self.len());
    let mut chars = self.chars(); 

    s.extend(chars.by_ref().take(1).flat_map(|c| c.to_uppercase()));
    s.extend(chars.flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase()));

    s
}
```

Comment: [Can be simplified and slightly optimized](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfa85b1d5e07d8e5e29785c5e530ee76).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
trait ToCapitalized {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String;
}

impl ToCapitalized for String {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String {
        match self.chars().next() {
            Some(c) => {
                c.to_uppercase()
                    .chain(self.chars().skip(1).flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase()))
                    .collect()
            }
            None => String::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", "fOoBaR".to_string().to_capitalized());
}
```

This will be a little slower than the ideal solution, as it decodes the first char twice, but it's quite readable IMO.

Output:

```
Foobar
```

Comment: @Jared it won't leak memory (the Boxes would get deallocated as soon as `collect` is done using them), but it would be terribly inefficient. Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Casting is *rarely* a good approach to solving type issues in Rust.  The correct solution here would be to write (or find a crate that defines) a type that unifies disparate iterator types.  But that would require *effort*, so it's simpler to just throw `collect` out the window:

```rust
trait ToCapitalized {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String;
}

impl ToCapitalized for String {
    fn to_capitalized(&self) -> String {
        let mut r = String::with_capacity(self.len());
        for (i, c) in self.chars().enumerate() {
            match i {
                0 => r.extend(c.to_uppercase()),
                _ => r.extend(c.to_lowercase()),
            }
        }
        r
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = String::from("canberra");
    println!("{}", buffer.to_capitalized());
}
```

This is, more or less, what `collect` would do *anyway* if you had some type to represent "either `ToUppercase` or `ToLowercase`".  In the *vast* majority of cases, this will also only perform a single allocation.

Comment: There probably is an Iterator type somewhere in the stdlib, but I doubt any of us will be able to find it. Honestly, I feel that there are too many, but I digress. This looks like the best solution because it simply forgoes the collect call for a similar for loop, which I think would be the smartest approach. Thanks for your input.