# Concise and safe way to replace certain ASCII chars with other ASCII chars in a string

Tags: string, rust

I want to write a function which takes a mutable string and checks if the first and last character are the `"` character. If so, those two characters should be replaced with the backtick character `` ` ``. I've come up with this solution:

```
fn replace_wrapping_char(s: &mut String) {
    if s.len() > 1 && s.starts_with('"') && s.ends_with('"') {
        unsafe {
            let v = s.as_mut_vec();
            v[0] = '`' as u8;
            *v.last_mut().unwrap() = '`' as u8;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work (yes, `` '`'.is_ascii() `` returns true), but it uses `unsafe` *and* looks a bit ugly to me.

Is there a safe and concise way to achieve what I want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544542/modifying-chars-in-a-string-by-index

Comment: Do you know if the whole string will be ASCII, or is it only guaranteed that the first / last character might be ASCII?

Comment: @Shepmaster I know nothing about the ascii-ness of the string. If the first/last character are `"`, then they are ascii (obviously...), otherwise no guarantee.

Comment: I guess what you'd want is if [AsciiExt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html) had a `set_ascii_char_at(index, new_char)` which returns a `Result<>` rather than panics if it can't work.  But there doesn't seem to be anything like that today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a safe, shortened version of that function, although it won't be memory efficient. This will create a copy and reassign the given string, so a pure function prototype returning a new string would probably be more fitting here. It also relies on the fact that the double quote character is 1-byte sized in UTF-8.

```
fn replace_wrapping_char(s: &mut String) {
    if s.len() > 1 && s.starts_with('"') && s.ends_with('"') {
        *s = format!("`{}`", &s[1 .. s.len()-1])
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e3909df15c1bc128f2771a11fc1ae3eb&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Noob question, but doesn't this copy the whole string and then re-assign it to `s`? Shouldn't there be a way to do this by just mutating the first and last bytes?

Comment: @Alec Exactly, this will copy and reassign the string, so I admit this isn't the best solution to the problem. Nevertheless, I'll just keep it here in case someone is ok with a copy.

Comment: @Alec *by just mutating the first and last bytes* — that's what OP's solution does, but it has to be unsafe because the type system can't guarantee that the first/last byte *was* ASCII and *remains* ASCII.